# how to solve TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer when normalising data using numpy in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to load columns 1 to 15 of the `data.txt` file into array X and column 16 into array y, and normalize all 15 columns in X in the for loop and array y in a single statement. Loading is working properly,  but after trying to print results of normalization I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Please help, the code is being done in python in the Jupyter notebook.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.loadtxt('data.txt')

X = np.array(data[:, 1:16])
y = np.array(data[:, 16], ndmin=2).T


n = X.shape

for i in range(n):
    X[:, i] = (X[:, i]-np.min(X[:, i])) / (np.max(X[:, i])-np.min(X[:, i]))
y = ( y-np.min(y) ) / ( np.max(y)-np.min(y) )

print(X)
print(y)
```

Comment: The ``.shape`` of a 2-dimensional array has 2 elements. What ``i`` do you expect the loop to iterate over?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably in the loop row `for i in range(n):`
n is X shape, its a tuple, range needs integer as parameter.

Code example of your case:

```
n = (2,4)
for i in range(n):
    print(i)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-277-3834a67eeb55> in <module>
      1 n = (2,4)
----> 2 for i in range(n):
      3     print(i)

TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

In your case, I think you want to iterate over columns, so `n = X.shape[1]` will fix it.

Comment: I have tried but I get the same error coming within the loop and the next statement

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-c3e34738309b> in <module>
      1 for i in range(n):
----> 2     X[:, i] = (X[:, i]-np.min(*X[:, i])) / (np.max(*X[:, i])-np.min(*X[:, i]))
      3 y = ( y-np.min(*y) ) / ( np.max(*y)-np.min(*y) )
      4 
      5 print(X)

<__array_function__ internals> in amin(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: Add the new code and new Error to the Question itself, It's not readable in comments.

Comment: What should I do when someone answers my question?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Decide if the answer is helpful, and then: -Vote on it  - Accept it
 https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer